# Grant write permission to local application pool group on a given folder

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have an IIS 7.5 stand-alone web server. I have 5 sites on it and each of them have a bout 9 application pools.

Now, I need to be able to grant write permissions to a local folder. I thought I could create a local group called 'AppPool - Site1' and grant that group the correct permissions on a given folder. I could then just add some or all of the app pools for Site1 and I should be fine, but...no...

It doesn't seem to work. If I grant the single user, 'IIS APPPOOL\Site1 - appPool 1', the exact same permissions, it works.

I want to do this with groups to keep maintenance easy.

Does anybody have any ideas or clues?

Answer (score 1):

The application pools are pseudo-users. The are members of a group named IIS_IUSRS. I had success adding this group to a C: drive folder.